# Change greyscaled img to black and white in photoshop

Tags: photoshop

How can I change in Photoshop CC a greyscaled jpg or pdf to just black and white (no grey and no color)?
I googled around but found nothing in that direction!

THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Image->Adjustments->Threshold

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you very much! That works like a charm :)! 
If you put your little tutorial in a answer I will mark that as the "accepted" answer :)!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. I won't put it as answer because it is not really a programming question - but thanks for the offer anyway. Happy Photoshopping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this:

**Method 1 - Two color PNG**

- Open your grayscale image in Photoshop
- Go File > Save for Web
- Set the file type as PNG-8, Colors: 2
- Then you can play with No Dither, Diffusion, Pattern, Noise to achieve different effects
- Save...

**Method 2 - Use a filter**
(I'm using CS6)

- Open grayscale image in Photoshop
- Go Filter > Filter Gallery > Artistic > Sketch > Stamp

**Method 3 - Threshold**
(as supplied by  Mark Setchell)

- Image->Adjustments->Threshold

**Alternate Illustrator Method**

- Open grayscale image in Illustrator
- Select the image on the stage, then go Object > Image trace > Make
- In the toolbar, there will be an Image Trace Panel button/icon, if you click this you will have options you can play with (Threshold)

Answer (score 1):

**one more method:**
GO image> adjustment> levels.

In input level collide the three sliders together.

you get different pattern depending on the position of the three sliders.